# Modal não abre ao mudar a página do datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

Tenho uma tabela de uma empresa que pegar os registro do banco, e uma datatable mais quando estou navegando por pagina, as vezes nao abre o modal com as informação.

```
<table id="table" border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>CNPJ</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Razão Social</th>
                <th>Fantasia</th>
                <th class='detalhes'>Datalhes</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table">
            <?php 
            $query = "select * from empresa";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                
                $id = $row['idEmpresa'];
                $cnpj = $row['cnpjempresa'];
                $email = $row['emailempresa'];
                $razao = $row['razaoEmpresa'];
                $fantasia = $row['fantasiaEmpresa'];
                // var_dump($result);

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$cnpj."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$email."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$razao."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fantasia."</td>";
                echo "<td class='detalhes'>";
                echo "<button data-id='".$id."' class='userinfo'>Visualizar</button>";
                "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Datatable

```
var table = new DataTable('#table', {
    language: {
        url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.13.6/i18n/pt-BR.json',
        },
    });
```

ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.userinfo').click(function(){                   
        var userid = $(this).data('id');
        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxfile.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {userid: userid},
            success: function(response){ 
                // Add response in Modal body
                $('.modal-body').html(response); 

                // Display Modal
                $('#empModal').modal('show'); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Answer (score -2):

Mude seu

```
$('.userinfo').click(function(){                   
    var userid = $(this).data('id');
    // AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxfile.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {userid: userid},
        success: function(response){ 
            // Add response in Modal body
            $('.modal-body').html(response); 

            // Display Modal
            $('#empModal').modal('show'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Para

```
$(document).on("click", ".userinfo", function(){
var userid = $(this).data('id');
// AJAX request
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxfile.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {userid: userid},
    success: function(response){ 
        // Add response in Modal body
        $('.modal-body').html(response); 

        // Display Modal
        $('#empModal').modal('show'); 
    }
 });
});
```

Quando há dinamização nos dados, ou seja, quando você necessita inserir mais DOM que necessitará obter os eventos deles também, você deve usar o $(document).on para poder prever os eventos futuros. Quando você instancia apenas o $(".classe"), você está apenas pegando os eventos dos elementos carregados no momento.